# WPF TextBlock binding with <LineBreak/>

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a TextBlock binding as follows in my ControlTemplate.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
 FontSize="16" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold"
 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=ButtonText}">
</TextBlock>
```

When I set ButtonText as follows with , it doesn't work. It doesn't display in separate line.

```
ButtonText="Change<LineBreak/> Casette"
```

How to fix this? Appreciate your help, please provide me with sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this code to obtain what you want. This is the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="16" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold"
           Text="{Binding Path=ButtonText}">
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

and this is the code behind. To make the example simplier, I don't create a ViewModel class:

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ButtonText = "Change\r\nCasette";
    }


    public string ButtonText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ButtonText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(Window1), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am changing it from XAML. Why doesn't it work from XAML? Should it be done from code behind?

Comment: Use this string: "Change&#x0d;&#x0a;Casette"

Comment: Do we really live in an age where the carriage return is still necessary? Why can't it just be a simple '\n' escape sequence. My keyboard doesn't have a carriage return armature anymore, and it no longer goes ding.

Answer (score 18):

A `TextBlock` displays the contents of its `Inlines` property.  The `Text` property exists only as a convenience (though it's a significant one):  if you set the `Text` property, the `TextBlock` will create a `Run`, set its content to the string you've provided, and save it in the `Inlines` collection.

When you set the content of a `TextBlock` element in XAML, the `XamlReader` populates the `Inlines` collection directly rather than through the `Text` property.  It parses text nodes into `Run` objects, and elements as usual for XAML.  So this:

```
<TextBlock>
   Line1<LineBreak/>Line2
</TextBlock>
```

is treated as though it were actually this:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run>Line1</Run>
   <LineBreak/>
   <Run>Line2</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Note, by the way, that if you try to set the `Text` property explicitly:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
      Line1<LineBreak/>Line2
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

you'll get an exception, because the `XamlReader` will try to create a `LineBreak` object, and the `Text` property can only contain a string.

Your binding isn't working the way you want it to because it's explicitly setting the `Text` property to a string.  This doesn't get parsed as XAML (and good thing, too).  And so what's displaying in the `TextBlock` is the content of that string.

So there are basically two ways to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.  In your case, you probably can just get away with embedding a newline into the string.

But this is trickier than it looks if you're doing it from XAML.  Because XAML is XML, and XML does some funny things to whitespace.  You're OK if you set it explicitly in an attribute using XML character entities, e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="Line 1&#x0d;&#x0a;Line 2"/>
```

But that won't work if you do it this way:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
      Line 1&#x0d;&#x0a;Line 2
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

because the XML parser normalizes whitespace in element content.  That CR/LF pair gets turned into a single space, and that's what gets into the text property.

If you're using binding, you don't need to worry about any of this XML stuff (unless you're binding to the contents of an XML document!).  You can just put `\r\n` into the property value.

The *other* way to do this is to directly populate the `TextBlock`'s `Inlines` property.  But you can't do this via binding, since `Inlines` isn't a dependency property - in fact, it's read-only, and you can only populate it by calling its `Add` or `AddRange` methods.